# How to test a component function being called when componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme, sinon

I have a React JS component `MyComponent` and I would like to test the following use case:

> It should call `updateSomething()` when component on mount

And I've come up with the following code:

System Under Test (SUT)

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    public componentDidMount() {
        console.log("componentDidMount"); // Debug purpose.
        this.fetchSomething()
            .then(() => {
                console.log("fetchSomething"); // Debug purpose.
                this.updateSomething();
            });
    }

    // These are public for simplicity
    public async fetchSomething(): Promise<any> { }
    public updateSomething() {
         console.log("updateSomething"); // Debug purpose.
    }
}
```

Test

```
it("should update something, when on mount", () => {
    const props = { ...baseProps };
    sinon.stub(MyComponent.prototype, "fetchSomething").resolves();
    const spy = sinon.spy(MyComponent.prototype, "updateSomething");

    shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
});
```

The result is the test failed with `AssertError: expected updateSomething to be called once but was called 0 times` but all three `console.log()` printed.

My understanding is since I want to test the event when on mount, I have to spy/stub it before it's even created, therefore I have to spy on `MyComponent.Prototype`. Also, for `fetchSomething()`, I have to stub the async call and make it `.resolves()` to let it progress.

But I couldn't understand how it can still `console.log("updateSomething")` without being spied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments/answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63353016/how-to-test-async-function-with-sinon-js/63353939#63353939), the assertion comes *before* `.updateSomething` have been called. To solve this problem, I would've to await the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

So the fixed program is as below:

```js
// SUT

public async componentDidMount() {
    //...
    return this.fetchSomething()
        .then(() => {
            //...
        });
}

// Test

it("should update something, when on mount", () => {
    const props = { ...baseProps };

    // Disable lifecycle here to enable stub in between.
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });

    sinon.stub(wrapper.instance(), "fetchSomething").resolves();
    const stub = sinon.stub(wrapper.instance(), "updateSomething");

    // Actually call component did mount.
    wrapper.instance().componentDidMount().then(() => {
         sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `sinon` and I don't know about `ts`, but with simple `js` and `jest` it'd be like this:

`fetchSomething() = Promise.resolve();`

Then, in your test, you wouldn't have to mock it and just use:

`const spy = jest.spyOn(MyComponent.prototype, 'updateSomething');`

To see if it was called:

`expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and this method has the same result of the OP.   
Simply doing  `MyComponent.prototype.prepareWithImageSize = () => Promise.resolve();` does not work for me. I ended up with the error msg `expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled(); Expected number of calls: >= 1; Received number of calls: 0`. But I can see the log inside `updateSomething()`. Do you have any idea on how this might happen in an async situation?

Comment: Ok, that's weird... but you could try assigning your shallow render to a variable and then spying like so: `const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'updateSomething')`. Nevertheless, I've no idea why the previous solutions don't work for you :(

Comment: np, still thank you for your effort. I will investigate a little bit more