# How to test async function with Sinon JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sinon

Below is a minimal example of what I want to achieve: I want to test `fn3()` being called if the async function `fn2()` resolved (when calling `fn1`). But I somehow failed to do that with `sinon`'s stub syntax. I would like to know what I misunderstood.

```js
// System Under Test

export function fn1() {
    fn2().then(() => {
        fn3();
    });
}

export async function fn2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // expensive work
        resolve();
    });
}

export function fn3() {
    console.log("fn3");
}

// Test

import * as Page from "xxx";

it("test async", () => {
    // stub this async to isolate the SUT
    sinon.stub(Page, "fn2").resolves();
    const stub = sinon.stub(Page, "fn3");

    Page.fn1();

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
});


/*

    AssertError: expected fn3 to be called once but was called 0 times

      276 |         Page.fn1();
      277 |
    > 278 |         sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
          |                      ^
      279 |     });
      280 | });

      at Object.fail (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:107:21)
      at failAssertion (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:66:16)
      at Object.calledOnce (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:92:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/test.test.tsx:278:22)
*/
```

Comment: You're asserting on the stub *before* the promise callback can possibly have been executed.

Comment: Do you mean when the program is inside `fn1()` and encounter the async function, it forks in the main function and keeps going to the assertion, therefore it asserts before the promise have been executed?

Comment: Sort of, I wouldn't describe it as a "fork" but the promise callback is added to the task queue, *not* executed immediately, whereas the assertion is on the call stack for immediate execution.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I think I am able to come up with a solution then.

Comment: import all the method with * is not allowed by most review tool, it is advised that you import only the method you will need except if you will need almost all the methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe suggested, your `sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);` will be called before the `fn2` promise inside `Page.fn1` is resolved (i.e. `.then(() => { fn3(); })` is called), based of the JavaScript "single thread, event loop" nature. Here's an article for reference: https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-promises-async-await-5gke.

You can try changing your code to:

```js
    ...

    return Page.fn1().then(() => {
      sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
    });
    
    ...
```

or

```js
it("test async", async () => {
    // stub this async to isolate the SUT
    sinon.stub(Page, "fn2").resolves();
    const stub = sinon.stub(Page, "fn3");

    await Page.fn1();

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
});
```

so that `sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);` will be called after `Page.fn1()` is resolved.

Comment: Thanks, it works! For the reference of other people, also change `fn1` to `export async function fn1() { return fn2().then(...); };`